# How to limit number of client connections for JSP page running on tomcat-8?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat8

I've made JSP project which is accessible by all machines connected to server.

eg.
**Accessible from All Computers Connected in Network**

[image: Accessible from any PC connected in Network]
s
**Accessible from All Mobile Device connected in Network**

[image: Accessible from Mobile Device]

Only 5 computers from client side should be able to access My JSP page residing at Server side.
How can I do it?

Thanks !

Comment: It's yet not clear, what you mean: one user should be able to connect from at max 5 devices at a time or any possible connections should be limited to 5 at a time.

Comment: Only 5 client machines should be connected to Server Machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i limit Tomcats Simultaneous Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320205/how-can-i-limit-tomcats-simultaneous-connection)

Comment: Do you need your application access to be limited within particular 5 devices inside your domain or do you need only 5 number of simultaneous connections to the application. Please clarify.

Comment: Only 5 computers from client side should be able to access My JSP page residing at Server side.

Answer (score 1):

In the server.xml , add the maxConnection property to the value you want :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxConnections="5"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Use [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) to get more information and details.

Comment: This didn't work !

Comment: I set maxConnections="2"
But I can access webpage from Server by using 3 client machines. :(

Comment: Please verify the port in config

Comment: Oracle uses port 8080 hence I've set port 8084 for Tomcat Server.